# Can JVM memory settings be set on an AWS Lambda?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We are getting

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
```

Since we are not using our full memory space, we figure it is the metaspace size.  I have seen a few posts that say we can set "some" jvm settings but I want to set some of these:

```
java -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=192mb (just example sizes)
```

1. Is it possible to set these settings?
2. Where in the yml can I do that?

**Update**

Here are the current settings from the lambda (via:
ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments())

```
-XX:MaxHeapSize=445645k, -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=52429k, -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=26214k, -XX:+UseSerialGC, -Xshare:on, -XX:SharedArchiveFile=/var/lang/lib/server/runtime.jsa, -XX:-TieredCompilation, -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Comment: Are you really wanting a 222GB heap?  Not with Lambda.  It's a 3ish GB environment max.

Comment: No, that was an example I found on the web.  Sorry.  Fixed.

Comment: See [modifying the Lambda runtime](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-modify.html)

Comment: you might be having a much bigger problem, metaspace isn't limited by default.

Comment: What is your current memory setting? What happens if you increase that setting? Do you get the same error when running outside of Lambda? Do you have any idea what is consuming metaspace?

Comment: Metaspace IS limited by default by AWS.  See above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're approaching this from the wrong direction. Per [the Java8 docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/considerations.html):

> The amount of native memory that can be used for class metadata is by default unlimited. Use the option MaxMetaspaceSize to put an upper limit on the amount of native memory used for class metadata

So, the only thing that explicitly configuring metaspace size does is *limit* the amount of metaspace memory; it won't increase it. If you want to give more memory to metaspace, you need to decrease predefined size of the rest of the heap.

However, that's the wrong thing to do.

The real problem is that you're doing *something* that loads more classes than can fit in available metaspace. The most likely cause is that you've just picked a memory configuration that's too small for your deployment bundle. You didn't say what your configured value was, but if I had to guess it's around 512 MB. Try 1024 or 1536.

It's also possible that you -- or one of the libraries that you use -- is dynamically creating classes in an unconstrained manner. In this case it doesn't matter how much memory you give to your Lambda, you'll eventually run out of space.

The way to diagnose this is to run your code outside of Lambda, using the `TraceClassLoading` and `TraceClassUnloading` flags. You're looking for classes that have "generated" names, typically random sequences of digits or letters.

Comment: Right.  But see new Update above.  We are not using our full memory footprint, so if we could increase Metaspace, we would be gold.  We just added the Snowflake driver and it is huge.

Comment: @markthegrea - while I'm surprised that Amazon explicitly sets that option, it doesn't change my advice: if this is caused by the number of classes you're loading, and not runaway class creation, then the correct solution is to increase your configured memory.

Comment: While you _could_ implement your own custom runtime that provides a different value for this parameter (or eliminates it entirely), the time to create _and maintain_ that custom runtime will buy a _lot_ of gigabyte-seconds.

Comment: I am surprised as well.  Yes, we increased the jvm size from 512 to 1024 and it fixed our problem, but it seems a bit odd that we have to spend money to fix this (it's not a lot).  Lambda is a commodity server and they would probably have trouble with people fiddling with the settings.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to setup max memory usage. Note: there are limits, min is 128 and max 3008 MB. See details [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html#cfn-lambda-function-memorysize)

Using serverless.yml

```yaml
provieder:aws
  memorySize: 512 # Overwrite the default memory size. Default is 1024
```

Using SAM template.yml

```yaml
LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      MemorySize: 512
```

If you plan to have a very custom setup there is custom runtime - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-custom.html
You need a bootstrap file which is the entry point and where you could define how the application is run.